# Convert gltf into FBX

Tags: mesh, .fbx, gltf

As the title says, I have a gltf file, and it opens more or less ok (textures are off).

This is the outliner:
[image]

Is there a way to convert this to mesh and then work in the usual way?

Many thanks!

Comment: If "Import glTF" → "Export FBX" is not working, you'll need to share much more detail about what you're trying to do, what you expect to happen, and what is happening instead. The screenshot of the outliner doesn't explain the question.

Comment: Those are empties from the hierarchy, and you need to expand them to get to the meshes. No need to convert anything